# how can i redirect video streams to another domain with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, video-streaming

How can i redirect video streams to another domain using htaccess? I am building a application where i can customize m3u playlists containing movies, series and live tv. I am writing a xtream-codes api emulator, so basically i am returning a different playlist (minimized / edited) - but i want the htaccess to redirect the streams request to the origin.

The playlist / api urls look like:
`/player_api.php?username=user&pass=pass&action=get_live_categories`

The stream url's look like:
`/user/pass/streamid.ts`

I tried redirecting with php, but this is not the way to go. I also tried to do a redirect on dns level - but thats not good because i can only redirect a complete domain / subdomain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.iptv-manager\.xxx$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php$).*)$ http://player-api.iptv-manager.xxx/index.php?subdomain=%1&route=$1 [QSA,P]
```

The above code routes any subdomain (wildcard) and route, which is then processed by the php code. But i cant seem to route the video streams through php.

[edit]
As a little bit more explanation of what i am trying to build: Im trying to create a alternative for the Xtream-Editor online playlist editor. Because of the way Xtream-Codes api works - it will get the base url (player_api) and use that with the stream-id's it gets to build a stream url;

As i want to be able to let users not only edit their m3u list, but also provide a customized list in xtream codes api players - if i set the providers host in the initial call to my player_api, it will load the streams and categories from the provider - and not the modified list the user wants to load.

So im not trying to resell streams under a different name - i already made a m3u editor that is widely used, but it is windows based, and requires users to manually update the list when the provider changes their streams.

Comment: So you want to implement a great service, but leave the hard streaming work to others? Hmmmm

Comment: No thats not what i meant to do - i already made a playlist editor for windows, but you will need to edit the playlist everytime your provider updates. I want to create a alternative for Xtream-Editor - where you can edit your playlist online.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get it done via php, `.htaccess` redirect only works for complete domain So use your `.htaccess` to redirect to php.

#### `.htacess`

```
RewriteRule ^live/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ yourphp.php?u=$1&p=$2&c=$3 [L,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ yourphp.php?u=$1&p=$2&c=$3 [L,NE]
```

#### `php` files

```
<?php
$c = str_replace (".ts","",$_GET['c']);
header("location: http://244.117.154.34:25461/".$c.".ch?u=".$_GET['u'].":p=".$_GET['p']."",false, 307);
```

That what you do to redirect xc to m3u or json to m3u